# Getting text content of <option> in <select> onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following select form input:-

```
const divisions = {
  pages: [
    { id: 1, text: "page text" },
  ],
  sections: [
    { id: 1, text: "option 1" },
    { id: 2, text: "option 2" },
  ],
  parts: [
    { id: 1, text: "part 1" },
    { id: 2, text: "part 2" },
  ],
};

const divisonSelection = division.sections;

        <select
          className="form-control"
          for={title}
          onChange={(e) =>
            setDivisionVariant({
              id: e.target.value,
              text: \\Here i want to show the selected <option> text value "v.text",
            })
          }
        >
          {divisonSelection.map((v, key) => (
            <option for={v.text} key={key} value={v.id}>
              {v.text}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
```

How can i get the value of the selected  in onChange event of the  element without the need to make a function outside the  element ?

Comment: Try placing id={v.text} to <option> and call e.target.id in onchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check this example:

```
import React from "react";

export default function SelectExample() {
    const divisions = {
        pages: [
            {id: 1, text: "page text"},
        ],
        sections: [
            {id: 1, text: "option 1"},
            {id: 2, text: "option 2"},
        ],
        parts: [
            {id: 1, text: "part 1"},
            {id: 2, text: "part 2"},
        ],
    };

    const divisonSelection = divisions.sections;

    function setDivisionVariant(param) {
        console.log(param, 'param');
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <select
                className="form-control"
                // for={title}
                onChange={(e) =>
                    setDivisionVariant({
                        id: e.target.value,
                        text: e.nativeEvent.target[e.target.selectedIndex].text
                    })
                }
            >
                {divisonSelection.map((v, key) => (
                    <option for={v.text} key={key} value={v.id}>
                        {v.text}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Worked text: e.nativeEvent.target[e.target.selectedIndex].text , Thanks